# Github Download Page / Button not visible anymore

Tags: github, github-services

I used to upload binary files using the downloads / add download ... button on the files tab in my repo. This functionality seems to be gone. Does anybody have any idea why? Temporary Github issue / browser issue / ...?

Answer (score 6):

GitHub uploads were discontinued on december 11th. See the [blog post](https://github.com/blog/1302-goodbye-uploads) for more information.

#### Summary:

> You can't upload anymore and the download tab is gone.
>   The download area and the downloads will continue to work for another 90 days.
>   Just add `/downloads` to the link of your repository.

EDIT:
Archive.org archived all github downloads that were available when github shut down uploading:
http://archive.org/details/github-downloads-2012-12

EDIT:
A similar to thing to downloads to launched July 2013: [GitHub Releases](https://github.com/blog/1547-release-your-software).
There you can add uploads to releases, which is what most people were doing with GitHub Downloads anyways.