# Github - where is the download page gone?

Tags: github, download

I have Github repos that offered pdf files as downloads. I remember pretty well selecting the pdf files as downloads and then following the download counter on the github pages. But now I wanted to set an external link to these download pages - and simply don't find them anymore.

Do I miss something, or have there been changes on github I did not notice?

Comment: same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13913708/github-download-page-button-not-visible-anymore (but that one was only a couple hours earlier and didn't have the github tag)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A change has been made: [they're getting rid of downloads](https://github.com/blog/1302-goodbye-uploads). You can read the blog post for details, but if you already have files uploaded, add `/downloads` to the end of the repo URL to view the downloads page.

Comment: I see, thanks, and the /downloads url will only work for 90 days more. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: You may also want to check out https://bintray.com (currently, in beta) as a new alternative for serving your binary releases from.

Comment: /download is hidden, but still seems to work - at least for downloading, upload is no longer possible

Answer (score 7):

In July, GitHub added a [releases page](https://github.com/blog/1547-release-your-software) that provides most of the features I remember from the old downloads page, and creates a tag in the repository to mark where the release came from.

Answer (score 0):

Open the pdf on GitHub. 
After that, click the raw button at the top right corner.